# multiple shared hosting accounts hosting different subdomains of same addon domain?

Tags: web-hosting, 301-redirect, shared-hosting, cname, multi-subdomains

I have two shared hosting accounts, each with limited storage space:
HostingAccountA with 'PrimaryDomainA', and HostingAccountB with 'PrimaryDomainB'.
A negligible amount of storage is being used directly by these primary domains.

If I'd like to create many subdomains of a third domain, 'AddonDomain', but the total required storage space is greater than what is available in a single hosting account -- is it possible to split the deployment of these multiple subdomains across more than a single hosting account?

Specifically, I'd like to add this *same* domain as an add-on domain in both HostingAccountA and HostingAccountB, and then somehow have it appear as if (in the end, maybe through a combination of CNAME- and/or 301-redirections?):

- HostingAccountA host subdomains: 'sub1.AddonDomain', 'sub2.AddonDomain', and 'sub3.AddonDomain'
- HostingAccountB host subdomains: 'sub4.AddonDomain', 'sub5.AddonDomain', and 'sub6.AddonDomain'

I realize that the nameservers for the 'AddonDomain' can only point to *one* of the hosting accounts, but not both. Thus it would seem that in HostingAccountB, subdomains 4, 5, and 6 would have to be created as subdomains of, say, 'PrimaryDomainB'.

Thus my question now becomes: is it possible -- perhaps via some mix of CNAME- and/or 301-redirections -- to have subdomains 'sub4.PrimaryDomainB', 'sub5.PrimaryDomainB', and 'sub6.PrimaryDomainB' appear to the end-user as 'sub4.AddonDomain', 'sub5.AddonDomain', and 'sub6.AddonDomain' (respectively), despite the fact that the nameservers for 'AddonDomain' are pointing to HostingAccountA (where 'AddonDomain' has already been defined as an add-on domain)?

Comment: If storage space is the issue and you need to host multiple domains and sub domains. Why not just use a company like Bluehost who gives unlimited domains and plenty of storage. How much do you pay total for each hosting account each month and year? Compare that to Bluehost, Hostmonster, etc.

Comment: That might be an even-smarter alternative, but right now I have a need to utilize specifically _these_ hosting accounts (for which I've already pre-paid).

Comment: Yes, if each server has a different IP. Just point the subdomains "A" records to applicable IPs and pick up the request with HTACCESS or vHost. All that matters is the IP when it comes to pointing subs. Routing to storage location is done after that point in a per-ip manner.

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on what your host will allow.  It is certainly possible to point your DNS record for a subdomain to a different web host entirely.  In that case you would certainly be able to use a separate account.

You host may or may not have the ability to have two accounts for the same customer and distinguish which one should have which subdomain associated with it.   To get further information you would have to ask your web host technical support team.

For a subdomain to be served from a hosting account two things need to happen:

1. The DNS for that subdomain needs to point to the correct server.   You can use either a CNAME or an A record.   Whichever your host tells you is appropriate
2. That server needs to be configured to serve documents for your subdomain.   A single server may host many domains and subdomains.  Each one must have a "virtual host" configured that specifies where the relevant documents are.

Comment: I'm asking for help with the specifics of how to correctly point the DNS records in this situation, assuming no artificial restrictions. Right now I can correctly browse to sub4.PrimaryDomainB.com .  Let's even assume that HostA is a totally different company, and that AddonDomain.com and sub1.AddonDomain.com (and sub2 and sub3) are already registered there. I tried registering a CNAME redirect from sub4.AddonDomain.com to sub4.PrimaryDomainB.com.  Should this theoretically work? (I _cannot_ browse to sub4.AddonDomain.com .) Maybe try 301-redirect or .htaccess instead?  How? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've added information to my answer.  Your CNAME should work fine for the DNS part.  My guess is that the server configuration (point #2) is where you are running into problems.  That is going to be the part where you will need support from your hosting company.